# How to automatically update fields in Office.js add-in for Word?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have an Office.js add-in that uses custom document properties. To update them i have to use deleteAll() because setting the value or a properties object gives weird generalexceptions and access denieds.

but deleting them all and adding them one by one works fine. But after the properties have been added, I have to press ctlr-A and F9 to update all the changed fields. Some are in headers footers so I have to select those and press ctrl-A/F9 there too.

In my VSTO i needed to call Word.application.activeDocument.fields.update() but is there something similar in Office.js? I scanned the API docs up and down but can't find a call that works. How do I update the fields in the document after I changed them?

In a docx we have a docProps/custom.xml which has something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns="schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/…" xmlns:vt="schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
  <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="Categorie"> 
    <vt:lpwstr>My category</vt:lpwstr> 
  </property> 
</Properties>
```

If we can bind those to content controls, that would be great. If that can be a 2way binding it would be awesome ;)

Comment: You might find it more reliable to use Content Controls mapped to a Custom XML Part for this scenario. Change the data in the Custom XML Part and the mapped content controls will update automatically.

Comment: hmm.. not sure I want to go that way. But my custom properties are in the document already as custom.xml having a fmtid a name and a pid. If I would add content controls to them instead and have the custom properties still editable (which i should because of legacy docs.. LOTS of them), I could try to build new docs with content controls even if they won't bind back to custom properties but how would i bind those properties to the content controls? Do you have an example on how to set that up with Office.js?

Comment: Could you provide a *very small* sample of the XML for the custom properties? The xml declaration, root element and a couple of child elements (complete) would suffice. Also indicate which element should be reflected in the document. Then we can see whether content controls can be mapped to this part...

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to put this *in the question* - it's not really useful in comments. And please include at least one entry for `<property>`.  This is Office 2016? This looks like it's the built-in XML part for  "Custom Document Properties" and not your own Custom XML Part? Not sure whether content controls can map to that...

Comment: ah right, done! there's more properties in the file but I added just one. they all have their own pid and name but the fmtid's are all the same. This is Office 2016 and you're right about this being a built-in XML part and not custom xml.